# WPF: binding through custom dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have an `TabControl` bound to a `Dictionary` and has a custom control as it's `ContentTemplate`. The custom control has a custom dependency property `Schedules` and it's `DataContext` is bound to a `ViewModel`, Here is how it look like:

Main control:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Schedules}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TabControl >
                <TabItem Header="Scheduled flights">
                    <views:MyViewer Schedules="{Binding Value}"/>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

In `MyViewer`, I also have an `DataGrid` that I want it to be bound the `Schedules` passed from the `TabControl`, but in the same time `MyViewer` has a `ViewModel` assigned to it. This is how it looks like in `MyViewer`:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Schedules}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
```

So far this is not working, when `MyViewer` is loaded `Schedules` property is `null`. But even if it works, I would want the Schedules to be passed to the `ViewModel` not code behind. One idea is to populate the Dictionary with `ViewModels` of `MyViewer`, but I do not wish to do this, I only want the Main control to know about details of `MyViewer`. So any clean idea to solve this?

***EDIT:***
The proposition above does work after changing to `ObservableDictionary`, but the question remains, how to have the `Schedules` in the `ViewModel`

Comment: you could use the tag property for that.
bind Schedules to Tag (you might need a converter) and set/bind the TabControl.Tag property to the value you want Schedules to be. Or else you would need to create a custom control that has the schedules property and the tabcontrol logic

Comment: So the `DataGrid` doesn't bind to the `Schedules` property of the `MyViewer`? Are you sure that the property is set, i.e. that the binding to `Value` actually works?

Comment: @mm8, it does bind after some modifications to the dictionary, but still I wish to have the Schedules in the `ViewModel`, what do you suggest?

Comment: @Ayoub.A: Bind the `DataGrid` directly to `Value`?

Comment: @mm8, That is what I want, to pass Value to the ViewModel of MyViewer. How do you accomplish that?

Comment: @Ayoub.A: `MyViewer` shouldn't have a view model. It should inherit its `DataContext`.

Comment: @mm8, Yes that would of been very nice, however, `MyViewer` has filtering functionalities that I don't want them to be placed in the `MainControl`

Comment: @Ayoub.A: Why don't you put the filter logic in the control? If the control has its own view model it cannot take part in the `DataContext` inheritance chain and this limits its usage.

Comment: @mm8, yes that is an option, but the business logic and view will be tightly coupled, since the filtering is part of the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyViewer` has it's own ViewModel, you should not rather do hacks like this:

```
   ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, 
   AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Schedules}"
```

This way `MyViewer` is tightly coupled to some other control.

Im my opinion, in this case, `MyViewer's ViewModel` should have it's own property `Schedules`. How could you keep `TabControl ViewModel's Schedules` and `MyViewer ViewModel's Schedules` in sync? It depends on your system, but you could try with this ideas:

- Sending ViewModel level messages like in MVVM Light, when adding or removing items. [Example in this blog post](https://wbsimms.com/mvvm-light-toolkit-messaging-example/)
- Try to implement some kind of store like in NgXs or NgRx in Angular
- Maybe you don't need to keep Schedules in sync - depends on your system? :)

Comment: `MyViewer` is the UserControl that has Schedules.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I skipped a word before:
MyViewer's ViewModel should have it's own property